# sshd not writing any kind of log Debian 6

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, logging

I just installed Debian 6 on my server and noticed that sshd isn't writing any log to /var/log. I understand this is a huge security issue as I won't be able to know who logged in to my server. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, sshd's `SyslogFacility` is set to `AUTH`.

If you haven't changed this in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you should be getting sshd log information in `/var/log/auth.log`. You'll also see messages here from pam and sudo, so all access information is logged in the same place.

Comment: Looks good in sshd_config:
# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

/var/log/auth.log doesn't exist.

Comment: Odd. All auth messages go there by default. You could check `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to confirm that it hasn't been directed elsewhere. Are your other logs being updated correctly? Is `rsyslogd` running?

Comment: Thank you so much! Yep you're right, for some reason rsyslogd isn't even installed. I installed rsyslogd and the ssh access log is in auth.log like you said. Is there a way to install all of essential packages? I had to install nano and tcpdump as it isn't included in my version of Debian. I think the version of Debian I have is the bare minimum.

Comment: I haven't gone through the installation recently, but I'd expect any default configuration to include rsyslogd. Unless it's **really** bare-bones, I'd just install things as you need them. Pretty soon you'll find it's all there.

Comment: I am tailing every file in /var/log and all I am getting is: 
Feb 15 07:21:40 zmijevik sshd[8764]: Connection closed by 234.234.234.234 [preauth], why is it not logging failed connections?